# What is the word I'm looking for? Similar to "aligns closely"

Tags: single-word-requests

Apologies if the title is a little ambiguous (it is a hard one to write).

I was going to write something like:

> Here at *company name*, we love that *chalet chef course* closely aligns/corresponds with how *company name* runs.

or

> Here at *company name*, we love that *Course name* is relevant and specific to the *company name* holiday experience.

---

"Closely" isn't the right word as what I'm trying to say is it aligns **exactly** with the holiday company's chalet experience (however 'exactly' isn't the right word either). Do you think option B would work?

Any ideas?

Comment: Similar to @KannE's suggestions - how about typifies?

Comment: @KannE: Yeah, *mirrors* is good. Or *This course accurately **reflects** our corporate ethos*.

Comment: Yes, *mirrors, reflects* or even *matches*, for that matter.

Comment: Whatever you do write, don't use: We love that....it sounds down-homey and corny as pie. But frankly, I'm having a hard time with your mishmosh of a sentence....:)

Comment: How about "coincides"?

Answer (score 1):

Since you elaborated on your second example, I presume that is your preferred example sentence. It further appears that *Course name* is **relevant and specific** to the *company name* holiday experience ***by design*** (and not by a fortunate accident). In that case, ***tailored*** is a suitable word.

> Here at *company name*, we love the way *Course name* is
>   ***tailored*** [relevant and specific] to the *company name* holiday experience.

ODO:

> **[tailor](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/tailor)**
>   *VERB*   [WITH OBJECT]
>
> **2** Make or adapt for a particular purpose or person.
>
> ‘Plans must be tailored to your business' goals, management style, size, resources and location.’